# Hook before woocommerce_order_status_completed is fired

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a hook before woocommerce_order_status_completed is fired?

I have installed a fedex labelling plugin that creates fedex label of a particular order and produces fedex tracking number. What i want to do is to create a condition that checks if the fedex tracking number is already generated when the user marks a particular order as COMPLETE or PAYMENT COMPLETED.

Comment: What do you mean by `woocommerce_order_status_completed`? I can see 3 instances of this string inside the plugin code... not sure which case you're referring to...

Comment: Hi, what im trying to do is to create a condition before making the order complete in woocommerce admin order page. woocommerce_order_status_completed is the hook that is used after the order is marked complete. What i want is before. Thanks.

Comment: Generally the order is marked as completed after payment is received. If the product is virtual then the order is marked as completed instantly. Or else it is marked as processing. You are you trying to do in the mean time? Some more information will be helpful to finding you a way out. You can find the update_status function in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php in line 1291

Comment: Hi i have installed a fedex labelling plugin that creates fedex label of a particular order and produces fedex tracking number. What i want to do is to create a condition that checks if the fedex tracking number is already generated when the user marks a particular order as COMPLETE or PAYMENT COMPLETED.